# Python - insert element at specific index without using insert function

Tags: python

just a heads up. My code probably is way off. I'm new and i'm trying my best to figure it out but i'm struggling

So far i have this:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):

    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
            i += 1

            return new_list
```

this is the code calling my function:

```
str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = list_function.insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
str_list4 = ['i', 't']
str_list4 = list_function.insert_value(str_list4, 'p', 0)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = list_function.insert_value(str_list4, 's', -1)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = list_function.insert_value(str_list4, 's', 7)
print(str_list4)
```

and:

```
num_list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list2 = list_function.insert_value(num_list2, 2, 1)
print(num_list2)
```

Am i far off in my solution? I really want to understand where i'm going wrong

Output is meant to be:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
['p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't', 's']
```

and:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

my output is:

```
['two']
['p']
None
```

this is all i get

Comment: can you share what your code is returning that's unexpected? That will help us help you.

Comment: just updated it

Comment: You indentation is off on the `def` an its contents. I'd fix it for you but I don't know where you want the `return new_list` to be. Shall I give it a go and you let me know if I got it right?

Comment: Im still trying to figure it out myself but If you could maybe give it a go and i can check. I would appreciate the help so much

Comment: Okay, all I did was indent the stuff under the `def` 4 spaces per line so they they stay aligned with the def.

Comment: python provides you the `list.insert(position, element)` can't you use that instead of creating your own?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I think that method does not handle negative indices the way OP wants to, e.g., If `position` is `-1` that method would insert the element the as second from the end rather than as the first element like OP wants, based on their expected output.  So they would still need to add some of their own logic.

Comment: @ShashSinha, good call. For the negative scenario, I just did `if insert_position < 0: insert_position = (-insert_position) - 1`. Or if we want all negative values to result in 0th position, then `insert_position = 0`. With this, we can still use `my_list.insert(insert_position,value)` to get the desired answer.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yup that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually extremely close, you just need to add some boundary checks:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    if insert_position < 0:
        insert_position = 0
    elif insert_position >= len(my_list):
        insert_position = len(my_list)
    
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
    
    if len(my_list) == insert_position:
        new_list.append(value)
    
    return new_list
    
str_list3 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
str_list4 = ['i', 't']
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 'p', 0)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', -1)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', 7)
print(str_list4)

num_list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list2 = insert_value(num_list2, 2, 1)
print(num_list2)
```

**Output:**

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
['p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't', 's']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. Im going to spend some time going over this to understand how it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close except that you've neglected to insert the lines from the original list and you return inside the loop instead of after its done. Also, there is no need to increment `i`. Its reassigned on the next loop with the next value from `range`. Basically, `range` takes the place of the increment.

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
    return new_list

str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
```

Instead of `range` you could use `enumerate` which counts but also gives you the lines iterated, so you don't have to index the array again.

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    for i,v in enumerate(my_list):
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
        new_list.append(v)
    return new_list
    
str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: I don't think this supports generating OP's expected output when passing in a negative `insert_position`, e.g. `-1` or an insert position that is bigger than the length of the current `my_list`, e.g., `7`.

Comment: thanks for the help. It was close and did give me more of an understanding on how it works

Answer (score 0):

You already have a few response on this question. Here is another option to consider:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    if insert_position < 0:
        insert_position = (-insert_position) - 1

    #if you want any negative value to result in position 0
    #then your insert_position assignment will be
    #if insert_position < 0: insert_position = 0
    #the rest of the code will remain the same

    my_list.insert(insert_position,value)

    return my_list

str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
str_list4 = ['i', 't']
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 'p', 0)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', -1)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', 7)
print(str_list4)

num_list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list2 = insert_value(num_list2, 2, 1)
print(num_list2)
```

The output for these will be:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
['p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't', 's']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

> #custom function for insert

```
insert_value =lambda a,value,idx: a[:idx] + [value] + a[idx:]
```

> example

```
str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
str_list4 = ['i', 't']
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 'p', 0)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', -1)
print(str_list4)
str_list4 = insert_value(str_list4, 's', 7)
print(str_list4)

num_list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list2 = insert_value(num_list2, 2, 1)
print(num_list2)
```

The output for these will be:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
['p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't', 's']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example but source list will change if need you can copy it

> Syntax: lst[index:index] = [obj]

Here is without custom function

```
str_list = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
str_list[1:1]=['two']
print(str_list)

str_list1=['i', 't']
str_list1[0:0]='p'
print(str_list1)
str_list1[-1:-1]=['s']
print(str_list1)
str_list1[7:7]=['s']
print(str_list1)

num_list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list2[1:1]=[2]
print(num_list2)
```

The output for these will be:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
['p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't']
['s', 'p', 'i', 't', 's']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```